# Bringing the html elements order properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have below html page:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6f9AE/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Extended UI</title>
<style type="text/css">

.header{
    padding-right:50px; 
}
.value{
    padding-left:50px; 
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="score"><span class="header">Score:</span><span class="value">10</span></div>
    <div id="dd-1"><span class="header">Has Account</span><span class="value"><select name="" id="">
                <option value="">Yes</option>
                <option value="">No</option>
            </select></span></div>
    <div id="dd-2"><span class="header">Has House</span><span class="value"><select name="" id="">
                <option value="">Yes</option>
                <option value="">No</option>
            </select></span></div>
    <div id="dd-3"><span class="header">Has Phone</span><span class="value"><select name="" id="">
                <option value="">Yes</option>
                <option value="">No</option>
            </select></span></div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

All the values are not displayed in order. How can i bring all the values order properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Order means, Are you talking about indentation and postion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Demo is here **[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6f9AE/8/)** 
Here is the Css changes you have to

```
.header{
    padding-right: 50px;
    min-width: 120px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.value{
    padding-left:50px; 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are applying padding to the inline element so it won't replicate your change first of all you have to make it `display:inline-block` and then specify width per your structure

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/HarishBoke/8HgHe/

Comment: Why so complicated, can be done with only one selector

Comment: yeah, we can achieve with tag selector also, but i intentionally define with classes, as per his structure

Answer (score 0):

How about using a simple table?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Score:</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Has Account:</td>
        <td>
            <select name="" id="">
                <option value="">Yes</option>
                <option value="">No</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Has House:</td>
        <td>
            <select name="" id="">
                <option value="">Yes</option>
                <option value="">No</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Has Phone:</td>
        <td>
            <select name="" id="">
                <option value="">Yes</option>
                <option value="">No</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yashhy/6f9AE/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can't set with for inline elements, but inline-block will work for you.

```
.header {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
}
```